# Create pyspark data frame from list?

Tags: pyspark

So I have a list of headers e.g.

```
Headers=["col1", "col2", "col3"]
```

and a list of rows

```
Body=[ ["val1", "val2", "val3"], ["val1", "val2", "val3"] ]
```

where val1 corresponds to a value that should go under col1 ect.

If I try `createDataFrame(data=Body)`  it gives an error `cant infer schmea type for str`

Is it possible to get a list like this into a  pyspark dataframe?

I have tried appending the header to the body e.g.

body.append(header) and then using the create data frame function but it throws up this error:

`field _22: Can not merge type <class 'pyspark.sql.types.DoubleType'> and <class 'pyspark.sql.types.LongType'>`

This is my whole code for this part for generating the body and header:

Basically I using openpyxl to read an excel file, where it skips the first x rows ect and only reads in sheets which have certain column names.

After the body and header has been generated I want to read it directly into spark.

We had a contractor who wrote it out as a csv and then read it in using spark but just seemed to make more sense to directly put it into spark.

I want to the columns to all be strings at this point

````
import csv
from os import sys
excel_file = "/dbfs/{}".format(path)
wb = load_workbook(excel_file, read_only=True)  
sheet_names = wb.get_sheet_names()
sheets = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").format("json").load(configPath)
if dataFrameContainsColumn(sheets, "sheetNames"):
  config_sheets = jsonReader(configFilePath,"sheetNames")
else: 
  config_sheets= []
skip_rows=-1  
#get a list of the required columns
required_fields_list = jsonReader(configFilePath,"requiredColumns")
for worksheet_name in sheet_names:

  count=0
  sheet_count=0
  second_break=False
  worksheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name(worksheet_name)
      #assign the sheet name to the object sheet


  #create empty header and body lists for each sheet
  header = []
  body = []
  #for each row in the sheet we need to append the cells to the header and body 
  for i,row in enumerate(worksheet.iter_rows()):
   #if the row index is greater then skip rows then we want to read that row in as the header
    if i==skip_rows+1:             
      header.append([cell.value for cell in row])
    elif i>skip_rows+1: 
      count=count+1
      if count==1:
        header=header[0]
        header = [w.replace(' ', '_') for w in header]
        header = [w.replace('.', '') for w in header]

        if(all(elem in header for elem in required_fields_list)==False):
          second_break=True

          break

      else: 
        count=2
        sheet_count=sheet_count+1
        body.append([cell.value for cell in row])```
````

Comment: Yes, it is. Using the syntax you describe. However, seeing as how that's not working, please show the entire code that generates the error.

Comment: ```spark.createDataFrame([ ["val1", "val2", "val3"], ["val1", "val2", "val3"] ], ["col1", "col2", "col3"]).show()
``` should work

Comment: have now put more of my code that generated the error @OliverW.

Comment: @pissall I tried that just now but I get another error around types?

Comment: @Tiger_Stripes What is the error?

Comment: @pissall 

```field _22: Can not merge type <class 'pyspark.sql.types.DoubleType'> and <class 'pyspark.sql.types.LongType'>```

I think I have to do something with the schema argument, like setting everything to strings?

Comment: I tried something similar to this and it has  worked

```schema = StructType([StructField(header[I], StringType(), True) for i in range(len(header)])```

But dates are currently messed up and replaced with java?

```java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?,areFieldsSet=false,areAllFieldsSet=false,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calenda ……..```

So may have to specify dates as being of a datatype

Comment: So @pissall answer does work but now need to answer this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59035055/dynamically-setting-schema-for-spark-createdataframe

With regard to dynamically setting the schema as it really hates dates if read in as a string

Answer (score 0):

There are a few method to create a dataframe from a list.
You can check them out [here](https://roizaig.blogspot.com/2019/11/spark-how-to-create-dataframe-different.html)

1. Let Spark infer the schema

```
list_of_persons = [('Arike', 28, 78.6), ('Bob', 32, 45.32), ('Corry', 65, 98.47)]
df = sc.parallelize(list_of_persons).toDF(['name', 'age', 'score'])
df.printSchema()
df.show()

root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- age: long (nullable = true)
 |-- score: double (nullable = true)

+-----+---+-----+
| name|age|score|
+-----+---+-----+
|Arike| 28| 78.6|
|  Bob| 32|45.32|
|Corry| 65|98.47|
+-----+---+-----+
```

2. Specify the types using a map transformation

```
list_of_persons = [('Arike', 28, 78.6), ('Bob', 32, 45.32), ('Corry', 65, 98.47)]
rdd = sc.parallelize(list_of_persons)
person = rdd.map(lambda x: Row(name=x[0], age=int(x[1]), score=float(x[2])))
schemaPeople = sqlContext.createDataFrame(person)

schemaPeople.printSchema()
schemaPeople.show()

root
 |-- age: long (nullable = true) 
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- score: double (nullable = true)

+---+-----+-----+
|age| name|score|
+---+-----+-----+
| 28|Arike| 78.6|
| 32|  Bob|45.32|
| 65|Corry|98.47|
+---+-----+-----+
```