# Dynamically setting schema for spark.createDataFrame

Tags: pyspark

So I am trying to dynamically set the type of data in the schema.

I have seen the code `schema = StructType([StructField(header[i], StringType(), True) for i in range(len(header))])` on stackoverflow

But how can I add change this into a conditional statement?

If header is in list1 then IntergerType, if in list2 then DoubleType, else  StringType for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague answered this for me

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField(header[i], DateType(), True) 
      if header[i] in dateFields 
      else StructField(header[i], StringType(), True)
      for i in range(len(header))])
```